# Proxypass changing URL Apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, url-routing

I am trying to connect my jupyter notebok server (:8888 port) via reverse proxy server

I have such rules:

```
ProxyPass "/serv8888"  "http://localhost:8888"
ProxyPassReverse "/serv8888"  "http://localhost:8888"

ProxyPass "/"  "http://localhost:80"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://localhost:80"
```

but when I connect to http://localhost/serv8888 it redirects internally to http://localhost:80/tree and basically I get http://localhost/tree and it does not work because I need to get

http://localhost/serv8888/tree what also means internally http://localhost:8888/tree

How to make it working? Please help me, I spent two days and almost gave up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

use `ProxyHTMLEnable On` to change the html on the fly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your "jupyter notebook server"'s internal redirect is attempting to undo what the proxy-pass is trying to do.  ProxyPass does not re-write content returned by the proxy's site.  It simply proxies communication to another web server.  If that other web server says go to "/some/url"... proxy pass will not change that.

You need to modify the jupyter's config and specify the `NotebookApp.base_url` to "/serv8888/"... and then proxypass will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not enough for me. I want to have not only jupyter on the server, but also other servers which I will access like http://localhost/server1, http://localhost/server2, etc. I've found `ModRewrite` but with my skills a string `RewriteRule        ^/(.*)$    https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1` looks like a magic

Comment: again, the child servers need to either *not* write URLs assuming they are hosted at "/", or you need to specify that the base URL is located elsewhere.  If this is not sufficient for you, you need to ditch apache's `proxypass` and look at an actual cluster-framework that is capable of rewriting http content on the fly.  I believe `squid` and other similar frameworks will suit your needs better.

Comment: ... and if you DO configure the base_url on your child-servers, you can host as many "servers" using `proxypass` as you want.

Comment: If I do not have any option to configure base urls of other servers? Is it possible to have another approach? And what is wrong with the usage of `RewriteRule`

Comment: Nothing is wrong, with the rules, but the links (a hrefs, script src tags, 301 redirects, etc...) sent by the child-server will all return data using "/" as a reference.  So, web-pages will includes a href="/something" not a href="/serv3888/something.  Javascript src files will be reffered to as "/js/something" not "/serv3888/js/something".   That's what YOUR child server returns.  Apache does not modify content being sent by that server.